# Slick Carousel doesn't appear on Boostrap page

Tags: javascript, css, carousel, slick.js

So I am kinda stuck with this Slick Carousel. It works great out of the box by itself, but when I try to incorporate it with my webpage, it just doesn't seem to show anything at all. I have no idea what is conflicting here. I tried to replicate it on CodePen and it works just fine, but not on my webpage. I have provided both the urls for your reference. Could any of you help me with this?

CodePen - https://codepen.io/jesse-alex/pen/jONpOrE

My Webpage - https://jessealex.com/test/test.html

```
(I have stripped the webpage of all other elements but the carousel)
```

Thanks a ton again :)

Comment: Check the console image files and css missing

Comment: You are importing css in a script tag instead of a link tag

Comment: should be `<link rel="stylesheet" src="infinite-slider.css">` not `<script rel="stylesheet" src="infinite-slider.css"></script>`

Comment: Thank you @TomBerghuis, I corrected it, but the page still doesn't display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a silly mistake... here are the fix

1. The element should be `<link>` rather than `<script>` as Tom Berghuis suggested.
2. Forgot to define the `type="text/css"`